# Anyfontsize Package Syntax

Tags: fontsize

For reasons of their own, the print shop wants text set at 22 pt on letter paper with 1" margins. So after a few runs of `\documentclass[22pt,letterpaper]{memoir}` and the error "unused global option [22pt]" (with no effect, of course) I found the `anyfontsizes` package. The documentation reads:

> `anyfontsize.sty` is a LaTeX 2ε package that lets the user select any font size (via e. g. `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont`)

So my questions about this package:

- why are there two size options? What does the second size option refer to if I want a global size of 22 points?
- Where does the command `\fontsize {with options}` go? I tried it after declaring the document class, no go. I tried it after `\frontmatter`, errors. I tried it after `\begin{document}` no effect.

Besides using the `anyfontsizes` package, is there another way that I can scale up the document font size to meet the printer's unusual needs? I understand that Latin Modern has fonts available at all sizes and that not declaring a font caused LaTeX to typeset in LM, but this didn't work either, i.e., `\documentclass[letterpaper,22pt]{memoir}`.

I know that the KOMA classes are more flexible with respect to font sizes, but there are chapter heading and page styles already typeset under `memoir` that I'd like to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use `[11pt]` and use the geometry package to specify half size letter paper with half inch margins, and then just print double size.
(or post process the pdf to scale it by 2, or use `\mag=2000` in the tex source.)

Comment: The geometry package documentation says "If you want to have a layout with two times bigger fonts, but without changing paper size, you can
type
• letterpaper, mag=2000, truedimen   // So, should "half size letter paper with half inch margins" be specified, or is the documentation correct?

Comment: @GMJones both:-) using `true` dimensions for page size would be an alternative way to do the same thing, if that is directly supported by `geometry` go with that:-)

Answer (score 7):

The `anyfontsize` package just redefines some internal macros for allowing `\fontsize` to select a font size also when the relative `.fd` file doesn't have an entry.

I'd avoid it, preferring

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
```

before `\documentclass`, which provides a better solution.

The package *doesn't* provide size options for document classes.

If you want to use a nonstandard main font size, you can look at the `extsizes` package, with the associated `extarticle`, `extreport` and `extbook` classes.

Also `memoir` has an extended set of options, but, as far as I know neither `memoir` nor `extsizes` provides for 22pt.

However, you can look at `size20.clo` in the `extsizes` distribution (on TeX Live it's in `/usr/local/texlive/<YEAR>/texmf-dist/tex/latex/extsizes`, change `YEAR` to the release you have on your machine) and modify the code for 22pt; add the modified code from `\renewcommand\normalsize` (included) to `\endinput` (excluded) in your preamble, surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.